# How to hash a password with bcrypt in mongodb without a page for registration?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, bcrypt

I have a problem. I would like to register a user in my mongodb with bcrypt directly (without have a UI for client, I want to manage it directly with querys) and login with REST API from client. It is possible or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can have a Node API running and then send a `POST` request to an endpoint you define with **Postman** for example:

```
// Routes file. Import this file later in your app.js or index.js file
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 
/*   ..... also import any user model, file, etc....*/


router.post('/signup', (req,res,next)=>{
     const username = req.body.username;
     const password = req.body.password;

     bcrypt
        .hash(password, 12) 
        .then(hashedPassword => {
            /* Your MongoDB logic. Example below */

            const user = new User({ // Example if you had a User Model
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword
          });
          return user.save();
        })
        .then(result => {
        // To be more RESTful this should send the whole user in JSON              format after creation**
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created!'}); 
        })
      })
    .catch(err => {
    // Error logic. This is just an example
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

To make it clearer you should have a `controllers` file too. If you also want a login then the logic would be similiar, create an endpoint and then send a request with Postman or some other app.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes! You are totally right I missed that. Edited the answer